# parallel foreach c# и разделение коллекции

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, распараллеливание

Можно ли как-нибудь задать правило по которому коллекция будет делится в parallel foreach c# между потоками?

По умолчанию, если ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism допустим равно 4, а коллекция состоит из 100 элементов, то первому потоку достанутся первые 25, второму вторые 25 элементов и т д.

А можно ли как-нибудь сделать, что бы первый прошелся по 1 5 9 и т п элементу, второй по 2 6 10 элементу и т д, третий по 3 7 11 и т д, а 4 по 4 8 12 и т д?

Вроде, есть какой-то класс, но он сам по себе достаточно сложный.

Можете ли вы привести примеры, которые позволят мне сделать желаемое поведение?

**UPD 1:**

В моей задаче коллекция представляет из себя коллекцию путей к файлам.

Каждый поток в parallel foreach берет по одному файлу и скармливает этот файл в `Process.Start` .

Деления, которое описано выше хочется ради того, что бы файлы обрабатывались параллельно в пределах одной директории, а потом переключались на следующую.

Т.е 4 потока сначала сидят в одной директории, а потом идут на следующую.

Это открывает мне дополнительные возможности: Например, так как я знаю, что директория была обработана, то я могу ее сразу удалить.

Comment: Таким образом вы напрочь убьёте производительность: будут постоянные промахи кэша. Непрерывный диапазон элементов грузится в линию кэша и эффективно обрабатывается ядром. А у вас в каждой линии кэша большая часть элементов будет ненужной.

Comment: Параллельные вычисления для того случая и нужны, когда порядок не важен. Вы делаете что-то не так, опишите кейс.

Comment: То, что вы описали - секционирование по диапазону.  В противоположность ему секционирование блоками, когда каждый поток берет почуть и по мере исчерпания добирает еще почуть достигая баланса и избегая простоев. Смотреть надо в сторону Partitioner.Create(..., true), который можно передать в Foreach или написать свой Partitioner

Comment: @vitidev а можно пример создания Partioner под мою задачу? Я когда то ковырялся в нем, но я не разобрался как достигнуть нужного эффекта..

Comment: @Monk, обновил вопрос.

Comment: Под вашу не могу. Ваша задача требует уведомления задач о том, что файл обработан и кто-то, кто следит за этим и может удалить папку. Для вашей задачи я бы делал Enumerable список, который бы выдал все файлы из одной папки, потом из следующей и отдельно следил бы за тем, что все файлы в папке выполнены. А если просто кровь из носа нужно обрабатывать файлы исключительно по очереди (а не просто сохранялся порядок), то просто не юзал бы Foreach, а использовал любой вариант с троттлингом

Answer (score 1):

Такое правило задать нельзя. Но если важен порядок на выходе, то можно воспользоваться расширением ".AsParallel().AsOrdered()".

```
var collection = new string[0];
var strings = collection
                  .AsParallel()    // параллелим 
                  .AsOrdered()     // хотим сохранить порядок
                  .Select(s => { return s; }) // обрабатываем
                  .ToArray();
```

На выходе получим параллельно обработанную коллекцию с сохранение порядка элементов. А дальше уже если нужно проходим по обработанной коллекции и выбираем нужные элементы.

Другие варианты (ручное разделение) будут давать просадку по производительности.

Есть ещё один вариант разбить исходную коллекцию на нужные диапазоны и запустить параллельные задачи:

```
var collection = new string[0];
var tasks = new List<Task<string[]>>();

tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => collection.Where(x => true).Select(x => { return x; }).ToArray()));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => collection.Where(x => true).Select(x => { return x; }).ToArray()));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => collection.Where(x => true).Select(x => { return x; }).ToArray()));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => collection.Where(x => true).Select(x => { return x; }).ToArray()));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

var result = tasks.SelectMany(t => t.Result).ToArray();
```

Всё будет вычислено параллельно с нужными критериями.

p.s. в .where задаём нужный критерий в .select вычисляем.

С учётом добавленного уточнения "**UPD 1**". Группируем коллекцию путей по папкам и выполняем каждую группу последовательно:

```
var paths = new string[] { @"c:\test\test.txt", @"c:\test\test2.txt", @"d:\test\test.txt" };
var groups = paths.GroupBy(p => Path.GetDirectoryName(p)).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(groups[i], path =>
    {
        // обрабатываем путь
        // Process.Start
    });
    Directory.Delete(groups[i].Key);
}
```

Или ещё один вариант:

```
var paths = new string[] { @"c:\test\test.txt", @"c:\test\test2.txt", @"d:\test\test.txt" };
var groups = paths.GroupBy(p => Path.GetDirectoryName(p)).ToArray();
Parallel.ForEach(groups, group =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++)
    {
         // обрабатываем путь
         // Process.Start
    }
    Directory.Delete(group.Key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

С учетом UPD задача решается просто.
По папкам - бежим линейно. В папке - параллельно.
Условно, это будет выглядеть как то так:

```
  foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories("."))
  {
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    Parallel.ForEach(files, s => { /* обработка файла */; });
    Directory.Delete(directory);
  }
```

Comment: А если сравнивать с вариантом, где вся коллекция посылается в Parallel с вашим решением, то на сколько просядет производительность?

Comment: На самом деле, зависит от файлов и скорости обработки. Лучше профайлера на ваш вопрос никто не ответит.

Comment: вроде, сам процесс инициализации параллельных вычислених достаточно ресурсоемок, а мы тут выполняем инициализацию N раз в зависимости от кол-ва папок.

Answer (score 0):

Для массивов и коллекций, реализующих `IList<T>`, `Parallel.ForEach` использует разбиение на блоки. Однако, для `IEnumerable<T>` используется описанное вами поведение: элементы равномерно раскидываются по потокам, поскольку размер `IEnumerable<T>` получить нельзя.

Иллюстрация:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 20);
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

Parallel.ForEach(source,
    value => {
        dict.TryAdd(value, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
);

foreach (var items in dict.ToLookup(x => x.Value, x => x.Key)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Thread ID {0}:", items.Key);                
    foreach (var value in items) {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(); Console.WriteLine();
}
```

В результате получим более-менее равномерное распределение по потокам:

```
Thread ID 6:
0, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17,

Thread ID 4:
1, 6, 8,

Thread ID 3:
2, 5,

Thread ID 5:
3, 10, 15, 18, 19,

Thread ID 1:
4, 7, 9,
```

Если же в качестве исходной коллекции использовать массив:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).ToArray();
```

То картина будет уже другая:

```
Thread ID 1:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9,

Thread ID 3:
5,

Thread ID 4:
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19,

Thread ID 5:
15,
```

Если вы хотите явно заставить `ForEach` равномерно распределять элементы по потокам, то, как уже было сказано в комментариях, вам необходимо использовать [`Partitioner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(source), options,
    value => {
        dict.TryAdd(value, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
);
```

Comment: А можно пример реализации  Partitioner под мою задачу?